# How to crop images in irregular shapes/polygons?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing, crop

I'm trying to crop an image by coordinates, in an irregular shape.
I do have the following polygon of coordinates where I have to draw a line and cut and keep only this polygon from the image.

These are the cooridnates (inside a canvas, starting clockwise)

```json
"polygon": [
   [0.152, 0.416],
   [0.16, 0.186],
   [0.172, 0.02],
   [0.211, 0.006],
   [0.357, 0.006],
   [0.592, 0.006],
   [0.656, 0.023],
   [0.775, 0.043],
   [0.789, 0.055],
   [0.756, 0.549],
   [0.756, 0.637],
   [0.736, 0.955],
   [0.719, 0.994],
   [0.607, 0.996],
   [0.197, 0.996],
   [0.131, 0.994],
   [0.123, 0.982],
   [0.125, 0.855],
   [0.139, 0.668],
   [0.139, 0.584]
],
```

What would be the best way/approach or tool to do this kind of job?

Inputs: image + coordinates of a polygon inside this image
Output: the polygon inside the image (or transparent/paint white the rest of the pixels that are not included inside the polygon)

Comment: In what form do you want the output? An array with only those pixel values? An image that preserves the neighborhood relations for those pixels? Something you can display on the screen?

Comment: Ideally something I can display on the screen

Comment: In that case all you can do is mask the region of interest, either making the pixels outside transparent or painting them with the background color. An image has to be rectangular, there is no way to show it on the screen otherwise.